# Insert into table uid from another table if it is not present in initial table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-into

I am sorry if this may be a duplicate but I have been searching on StackOverflow for a while and can not see anything that exactly fits the query I am looking to do.

Basically, I have a user database that I have recently created options to the users but only for users that were level 1.

Now I am wanting to change that and give options to everyone no matter what their level is.

I am looking to go through all users that are currently in the database and if no options are found in the urights for that user with the relationship of uid=id then insert options using the user id from the user table.

I have been playing with the injection for a while but I just can not seem to get it to work.

[Here is a sqlfiddle I have created](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01f30/13)

My latest 3 queries I have used are:

```
insert into urights ('', u.id, 1, 1, 0) (SELECT u.id FROM usr u WHERE (SELECT ur.id FROM urights ur WHERE ur.uid != u.id) )

SELECT id FROM usr u (INSERT INTO urights (id, uid, quotes, pos, nmode) VALUES ('', u.id, 1, 1, 0) WHERE uid NOT IN (u.id))

INSERT INTO urights (id, uid, quotes, pos, nmode) VALUES ('', a.id, 1, 1, 0) SELECT a.id FROM usr a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ur.uid FROM urights ur WHERE AS ur.uid = a.id)
```

Any pointers in what I am doing wrong and guidance to correcting this is most appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can massively simplify this problem. Start with a table containing only two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer, this way you still iterate over the user id that aren't present while setting the other values in the same statement.

```
INSERT urights (uid, quotes, pos, nmode) 
SELECT DISTINCT u.usernumber, 1, 1, 0
FROM usr u
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT uid FROM urights ur
          WHERE ur.uid = u.usernumber);
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62b0ff9/1

Comment: Hi @likwidfire2K, and thank you for taking the time to help. The issue with this is it is changing all the existing user's permissions that were already in the urights database.

Comment: @Robert ok, so the quotes, pos and nmode are currently different for each user that already exists, but it is going to be set to the same number for all new users added correct?

Comment: thank you so much, and it is so simple the way you have done it. I think I was trying to over complicate the sql code.